# Adding a Class to @Html.DropDownList Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

```
    @Html.DropDownList(productOption.Option.Id.ToString(), productOption.ValuesInOptions.ToSelectList(f => f.OptionValue.OptionValue1, 
                                               f => f.Id.ToString(), 
                                               "Select"));
```

How would I add a class to the above @Html.DropDownlist() within a razor view?

Answer (score 3):

You can use it's overload, that accepts providing html attributes:

```
@Html.DropDownList(productOption.Option.Id.ToString(), productOption.ValuesInOptions.ToSelectList(f => f.OptionValue.OptionValue1, 
                   f => f.Id.ToString(), 
                   "Select"), new {@class = "some-class"});
```

Comment: you could remove the ToString() part of your dropodwn too.

Comment: `DropDownList` has `string` as the first argument, so `ToString` is required